# Is there a Java interface for managing UNIX ACL

Tags: java, unix, acl

I have a need to manage UNIX ACL (Access Control List) on files in a file system, and it includes query & modification of ACE (Access Control Entry) on different types of UNIX systems like Linux, SUN etc. with POSIX, NFS style file systems.

My first thought was to create a wrapper or an interface on top of the file system services to handle these ACL needs.

Is anybody aware of any such Java API that can be used for the purpose?

Comment: Java has [a few](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/AclEntry.Builder.html) [different](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/acl/Acl.html) [ACL implementations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/acl/AclEntry.html) in the documentation.  I've never used any of them, however, so I'm not sure if they'll work for your exact purpose. Have you tried them out before?

Answer (score 2):

> Is anybody aware of any such Java API that can be used for the purpose?

Yes there is one.  It is [`java.nio.file.attribute.AclFileAttributeView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/AclFileAttributeView.html) which is part of the NIO enhancements added in Java 7.

There is a simple example in the javadoc for the above class.

(The `java.security` ACL stuff is for access control implemented by / within Java security.  That is orthogonal to ACL support at the file-system level.)

Comment: Yes that is something I was looking for but it seems it supports only NFSv4 style ACL. Some file systems like the one in SUN OS seems to be using some other style and also some older LINUX systems are using something other than that. Any ways it gave me some direction. Thanks

Comment: @Acharya - I think you might find that on SunOS/Solaris that that the class *does* work.  (The api talks about an ACL "model" ... not a specific implementation, and it would be weird for an Oracle Java not to support Oracle's flag-ship operating system properly.)  But for old Linux systems, you might be out of luck ... unless you can find a Java 7 version that is advertised as "supported" for the old Linux platform.